# How much statement can be made conditional in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, switch-statement, case

the MySQL manual [says](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html) that a CASE statement (the WHEN part) can contain a statement_list.

**How much statement is that to be exact?** I need to perform a pretty big query which I would like to parametrize. However this also implies that I need to change tables that are being joined. I've read that this cannot be done using CASE statements, so I'm looking for a solution to not have to re-create the stored procedure for every parameter value that there is...

**UPDATE**
I tried to solve it using a CURSOR. I have defined a CURSOR for every object I have. I would like to use IF-ELSE-statements to choose which cursor to open, loop and close. However I cannot get the syntax right...

All cursors and variables (usb, obj, mm, stamp) are declared with different names, but I've shortened them for reading....

```
if OBJECTTYPE = 1 then
open CUR_1_BUILDING;
LOOP1: loop
    fetch CUR_1_BUILDING into usb, obj, mm, stamp;
    if no_more_rows then
        close CUR_1_BUILDING;
        leave loop1;
    end if;
    INSERT INTO ObjectCache (usb, obj, mm, date_checked) VALUES (usb, obj, mm, now());
end loop LOOP1;
    CLOSE CUR_1_BUILDING;
else if OBJECTTYPE = 2 then
open CUR_2_CITY;
LOOP2: loop
    fetch CUR_2_CITY into usb, obj, mm, stamp;
    if no_more_rows then
        close CUR_2_CITY;
        leave loop2;
    end if;
    INSERT INTO ObjectCache (usb, obj, mm, date_checked) VALUES (usb, obj, mm, now());
end loop LOOP2;
    close CUR_2_CITY;
end if;
```

Is this is any way possible to do using CASE statements?

```
BEGIN
    CASE
        when OBJECTTYPE = 1
            INSERT INTO ObjectCache SELECT id FROM Building
        when OBJECTTYPE = 2
            INSERT INTO ObjectCache SELECT id FROM City
    END CASE;
END
```

Comment: I had a sneaky typo, ELSE IF should be ELSEIF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `IF ELSE` or you could build and execute dynamic SQL.

Comment: But i have more than 2 OBJECTTYPES, does this mean I cannot use IF ELSE?

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work on my complex query... I have a syntax error at line 96; (which is empty), the script goes till 95; I'm gonna try a little further, otherwise i'll post another sample